# Validar chave composta com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-validation

Possuo uma tabela onde são inseridos os funcionarios de uma empresa com os seguintes campos; `id`, `name`, `email`, `use_id`, `role_id`.

> `user_id` é o `id` da empresa que o funcionario trabalha.

A validação que necessito fazer é verificar se o `email` já esta atrelado á `empresa`, pois este funcionario pode ser registrado para outras empresas mas nunca 2x para a mesma empresa, em resumo um email pode ser cadastrado mais de 1x contanto que não seja para o mesmo `user_id`(empresa)

[Seguindo a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique) adicionei a seguinte regra:

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|'.Rule::unique('employees')->where(function($query){
           $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        }),
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'role_id' => 'integer'
];
```

Porém a validação nunca aplica o `and` para a verificação; `where email = 'x' AND user_id = 'y'`

#### Exemplo:

Os seguintes registros abaixo são válidos:

```
| id | user_id |  email     |
|--------------|:----------:|
| 1  |    4    | x@x.com.br |
| 2  |    5    | x@x.com.br |
```

O seguinte é **inválido**:

```
| id | user_id |  email     |
|--------------|:----------:|
| 1  |    4    | x@x.com.br |
| 2  |    4    | x@x.com.br |
```

No primeiro exemplo o mesmo email é usado com `user_id` diferentes então a inserção/validação é válida, no segundo exemplo é inválido pois o `user_id` já esta atrelado ao email `x@x.com.br"

Um bom exemplo é um `SASS` de e-commerce, onde varios clientes podem pertencer a diversas lojas (que estarão na mesma tabela)

Comment: Na verdade o e-mail não pode repetir correto?

Comment: Sim, pode se repetir desde que a coluna `user_id` não se repita para o mesmo e-mail, esse é o princípio de chave composta

Comment: Então tem alguma coisa estranha ... bom mesmo assim a resposta abaixo eu fiz a respeito do erro na hora de escrever a regra, dá uma olhada

Comment: @VirgilioNovic coloquei alguns exemplos para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Caro Rafael, Ok, vejo problemas nisso, mas, é meu conceito, agora eu gostaria de saber se a resposta deu certo, porque, você perguntou disso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Tente assim:***

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'email' => ['required','email','max:255', Rule::unique('employees')
         ->where(function($query) { $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id); })
    ],
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'role_id' => 'integer'
];
```

***Qual foram as diferenças?***

No lugar do ponto era uma virgula e a validação nesse caso é um `array` igual descrito na documentação.

<sub>***Referencia***</sub>

- [validation#rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: a validação não aceita `arrays` como valor; `Method [validateRequired|email|max] does not exist.`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, é um array, dá uma olhada na edição, passou para mim desapercebido ...